# Nodemon crashed error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> C:\Users\dell india\Desktop\Mean\News_Portal\News_Portal\api>nodemon
>   [nodemon] 1.11.0   [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
>   [nodemon] watching: *.*   [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
>   events.js:182
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^

­

> Error: spawn cmd ENOENT at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:189:19) at onErrorNT
>   (internal/child_process.js:366:16) at _combinedTickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11) at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)

Comment: This should be under puzzles section...

Comment: Please add more details regarding the problem and what you have already tried to solve it.